# How do I merge data into Multidimentional array based on a value in current/previous array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I am building some phone statistics and have the output below which I need to basically merge the same src and add the duration together. For example array index 0 through to 6 would merge into one array that would look like the following:

```
[0] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:31:47 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 190 )
```

You're probably thinking shouldn't it be index 0 through to 8 but because index 6 was only 10 seconds this basically signifies that the call was answered. It can be assumed that if a call duration is 30 seconds then it has not been answered.

It's not as simple as just finding the src that match in the array and adding all the durations together though as you will see in `index 11` `9123` calls and is answered within 12 seconds but they call back around 30 minutes later and their second call at `9:55:31` is answered within 15 seconds, this would need to be to separate items in the final array.

The src's are just fictional and will not be the numbers in the real world.

```
Array ( 

    [0] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:31:47 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:32:22 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:32:57 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:33:32 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:34:07 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:34:42 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:35:12 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 10 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:35:47 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:36:22 [src] => 1234 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 08:51:20 [src] => 5678 [duration] => 15 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:09:14 [src] => 5678 [duration] => 10 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:22:58 [src] => 9123 [duration] => 12 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:42:42 [src] => 4567 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:43:17 [src] => 4567 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [14] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:43:52 [src] => 4567 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [15] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:44:27 [src] => 4567 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [16] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:45:02 [src] => 4567 [duration] => 29 ) 
    [17] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 09:55:31 [src] => 9123 [duration] => 15 ) 
    [18] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 10:34:29 [src] => 8912 [duration] => 10 ) 
    [19] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 13:26:29 [src] => 3456 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [20] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 13:27:04 [src] => 3456 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [21] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 13:27:39 [src] => 3456 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [22] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 13:28:14 [src] => 3456 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [23] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 13:28:49 [src] => 3456 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [24] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 13:29:24 [src] => 3456 [duration] => 30 ) 
    [25] => Array ( [calldate] => 2014-12-01 13:29:54 [src] => 3456 [duration] => 4 ) 
)
```

I believe this would need to be some sort of for loop that would have to compare current/previous calls and add them into a new array. I have done this but it isn't giving the expected result as it only adds together the previous and current call if the src matches. Here is the code I currently have:

```
$adjusted = array();
for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($adjustedTotalCallsExt); $i++) {
$previousCall = $adjustedTotalCallsExt[$i-1];
$currentCall = $adjustedTotalCallsExt[$i];
    if($previousCall['src'] == $currentCall['src']) {
        $adjusted[] = $previousCall['duration'] + $currentCall['duration'];
    }
    else {
    $adjusted[] = $currentCall['duration'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to separate out each call based on answered in separate instances, *PLUS* you want to count same named `src` differently based on each instance, this will break your array down into sections based on spans of time (well, not real time, just the array key differences). Note, you can break this down one more time to just isolate each instance of total if you want:

```
$calls = array(
                0 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:31:47', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ),
                1 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:32:22', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ),
                2 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:32:57', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                3 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:33:32', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                4 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:34:07', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                5 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:34:42', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                6 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:35:12', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 10 ), 
                7 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:35:47', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                8 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:36:22', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                9 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 08:51:20', 'src' => '5678', 'duration' => 15 ), 
                10 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:09:14', 'src' => '5678', 'duration' => 10 ), 
                11 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:22:58', 'src' => '9123', 'duration' => 12 ), 
                12 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:42:42', 'src' => '4567', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                13 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:43:17', 'src' => '4567', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                14 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:43:52', 'src' => '4567', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                15 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:44:27', 'src' => '4567', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                16 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:45:02', 'src' => '4567', 'duration' => 29 ), 
                17 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 09:55:31', 'src' => '9123', 'duration' => 15 ), 
                18 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 10:34:29', 'src' => '8912', 'duration' => 10 ), 
                19 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:26:29', 'src' => '3456', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                20 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:27:04', 'src' => '3456', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                21 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:27:39', 'src' => '3456', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                22 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:28:14', 'src' => '3456', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                23 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:28:49', 'src' => '3456', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                24 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:29:24', 'src' => '3456', 'duration' => 30 ), 
                25 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:29:54', 'src' => '3456', 'duration' => 4 ),
                26 => array('calldate' => '2014-12-01 13:29:54', 'src' => '1234', 'duration' => 30 )
            );
$i = 0;
foreach($calls as $row) {

        $user[$row['src']][$i]['calls'][]   =   $row['duration'];
        $user[$row['src']][$i]['duration']  =   array_sum($user[$row['src']][$i]['calls']);

        if($row['duration'] < 30) {
                $i++;
            }
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
```

**WILL GIVE YOU:**

```
Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30
                            [1] => 30
                            [2] => 30
                            [3] => 30
                            [4] => 30
                            [5] => 30
                            [6] => 10
                        )

                    [duration] => 190
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30
                            [1] => 30
                        )

                    [duration] => 60
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30
                        )

                    [duration] => 30
                )

        )

    [5678] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 15
                            [1] => 10
                        )

                    [duration] => 25
                )

        )

    [9123] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                        )

                    [duration] => 12
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 15
                        )

                    [duration] => 15
                )

        )

    [4567] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30
                            [1] => 30
                            [2] => 30
                            [3] => 30
                            [4] => 29
                        )

                    [duration] => 149
                )

        )

    [8912] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                        )

                    [duration] => 10
                )

        )

    [3456] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [calls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30
                            [1] => 30
                            [2] => 30
                            [3] => 30
                            [4] => 30
                            [5] => 30
                            [6] => 4
                        )

                    [duration] => 184
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Rasclatts your answer separates the different calls at different times which is exactly what I need. Now I will build another for loop to go through the new array to find calls that are under 30/60 second duration. I modified Rasclatts code in the If statement so that duration was < 30 rather than < 15 as that was merging the 5678 src call which was around 30 minutes apart. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$adjusted = array();
        for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($adjustedTotalCallsExt); $i++) 
        {       
                $adjusted[$adjustedTotalCallsExt[$i]['src']]['duration']=$adjusted[$adjustedTotalCallsExt[$i]['src']]['duration']+ $adjustedTotalCallsExt[$i]['duration'] ;         
        }
```

Hope it will serve your purposes. Please let me know if it didnt work for you.

Comment: I think you are missing `[$i]` in there.

Comment: Yes you are correct Rasclatt. Thanks for the rectification.

Comment: Hi Tristup, that worked but it totaled up the src calls even if they were at different times.

Comment: I didnt get you Elliot. Please tell me about so I can help you.